# How to check if something is x fold in Python?

Tags: python

So, I am trying to make this program and I am very close now, but I can't make the finishing touch. I traced my problem, as the problem lies in the usage of modulo. I am trying to get the fivefold of e, but when I do that, I get -2 for the third element in my list, which is not something I'd expect.

It's probably because I am trying to divide a negative number with modulo, but I can't fix the problem as I don't know how. Could someone help me out with this, please?

```
def f10(start, n):
    """
    The parameters start and n are both int's. Furthermore n > 0.
    The function f10() should return a list of int's that contains n
    elements.
    The first element (e) in the resulting list has to be start.
    The successor of an element e is calculated as follows:
    - if e is a fivefold (e.g. n is divisible by 5),
      then the next value of e is e / 5
    - if e is not a fivefold, then the next value of e is e - 4

    Example:
        f10(1, 10) should return
        [1, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3]
        f10(9, 12) should return
        [9, 5, 1, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3]
    """

    pass

    new_list = []
    k = range(start, n+1)
    e = k[0]

    new_list.append(e)

    for e in k:
        if e % 5 == 0:
            e = float(e) / 5
        else:
            e -= 4

        new_list.append(e)

    return new_list

print f10(1, 10)
print f10(9, 12)
```

So, I should get:

```
[1, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3]
```

But I get

```
[1, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2.0]
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `e = float(e) / 5` I wouldn't do that. Why not `e //= 5` ? you don't want floats right (note: it doesn't change the result, but still)

Comment: `for e in k`? That's not how you're supposed to be setting `e`.

Comment: in loop you assign value from `k` to `e` but you have to use previous `e` in calcualtion.

Comment: What do you mean? Why can't I set it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use previous value to calculate new one.

```
def f10(start, n):

    result = [start] # I put first element

    for _ in range(n-1): # I have to put other n-1 elements yet
        if start % 5 == 0:
            start //= 5
        else:
            start -= 4

        result.append(start)

    return result

# --- compare result with expected list ---

print(f10(1, 10) == [1, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3])
# True

print(f10(9, 12) == [9, 5, 1, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3, -7, -11, -15, -3])
# True
```

---

**EDIT:** if you don't want `range()` then you can use `while len(result) < n:`

```
def f10(start, n):

    result = [start]

    while len(result) < n:
        if start % 5 == 0:
            start //= 5
        else:
            start -= 4

        result.append(start)

    return result
```

Comment: Never mind. Got it! Thank you, I like the simple style.

Comment: because result need `n` elements and I put first before `for` loop in `result = [start]`

Comment: is there a possibility to NOT use range? I mean, could you provide one without using range in the for?

Comment: range is most natural method - but you can use `while` with some variables to count elements.

Comment: or using `while len(result) < n:`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here. Most importantly you are trying to use the variable e to both iterate over your loop and to store results of your calculations.

Try this:

```
def f10(start, n):
    x = start
    new_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        new_list.append(x)
        x = x-4 if x%5 else x//5
    return new_list
```